# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected - SQLDeveloper

Tags: oracle

I have had a look through all relavent questions to this 00923 Error on StackOverflow and cannot find an answer which works so I'm posting my own question.

I am working with SQL Developer and trying to run this command below:

```
SELECT *,(
CASE dayOfWeek
    WHEN 1 THEN "Monday"
    WHEN 2 THEN "Tuesday"
    WHEN 3 THEN "Wednesday"
    WHEN 4 THEN "Thursday"
    WHEN 5 THEN "Friday"
    WHEN 6 THEN "Saturday"
    WHEN 7 THEN "Sunday"
END) AS "dayOfWeek"
FROM Schedules WHERE routeID = 1;
```

I have days of the week as an integer from 1 to 7 respectively in the database. I am trying to use this CASE to display 1 to 7 as Text as shown above and am receiving this error.

Error In Full Below:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 9
```

Comment: You've missed aliases. 

`select alias.* ,(case ....) from schedules alias ....`

Answer (score 2):

When using `*` within your SELECT clause with more than just the `*` you need to qualify the `*` with the table name from which you'd like the records.

```
SELECT Schedules.*,
CASE dayOfWeek
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday'
END AS "dayOfWeek"

FROM Schedules WHERE routeID = 1;
```

Comment: ORA-00904: "Sunday": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 17

I am now getting this error.

Comment: Oh you need single quotes around the date names. Please see edited answer.

Comment: Would there be a way to move the added column "dayOfWeek" as specified in code above to be in the middle of the table?

Image Here: http://i.imgur.com/90jgibd.png

Comment: To do that you'd need to write out all of the column names.

Comment: Just realised that the case is part of the select statement, duh. See my posted answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I posted another problem below in relation to the error in the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Schedules.ScheduleID, Schedules.RouteID,
CASE dayOfWeek
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday'
END AS "dayOfWeek", Schedules.depTime, Schedules.arrTime, Schedules.Status
FROM Schedules WHERE routeID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of Visual Studio when I'm executing that SQL statement, I receive the same error as mentioned in the title of this post. Code snipper from method below.

```
public static DataSet getRouteSchedules(DataSet DS, int routeID)
        {
            con = new OracleConnection(DBConnect.oradb);
            con.Open();

            string SQL = @"SELECT Schedules.ScheduleID, Schedules.RouteID,
                            CASE Schedules.dayOfWeek
                            WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday'
                            WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday'
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday'
                            WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday'
                            WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday'
                            WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday'
                            WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday'
                           END AS 'dayOfWeek', Schedules.depTime, Schedules.arrTime, Schedules.Status
                           FROM Schedules WHERE routeID = " + routeID;

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(SQL, con);
            OracleDataAdapter DA = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

            try
            {
                DA.Fill(DS, "Schedules");
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            con.Close();

            return DS;
```

Comment: You need to have double-quotes around `dayOfWeek`.

Comment: That breaks the Statment then. As the entire Statment is enclosed in Double-Quotes also. Best way around that?

Comment: Fixed it by leaving out Single or Double-Quotes around dayOfWeek.