# FROM keyword not found where expected 00923. 00000 - "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, oracle

select *,
(case when this.testtype in
( select testtype from Offer as o where o.testcenter=t.testcenter)
then 'yes' else 'no' end)
as offered
from Test as t;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected - SQLDeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939581/ora-00923-from-keyword-not-found-where-expected-sqldeveloper)

Answer (score 2):

The `AS` keyword is not syntactically valid before a table alias. You need to remove it from the outer query and from the sub-query.

You also need the table alias before the columns wildcard `*` when you are selecting other columns:

```sql
select t.*,                                     -- t.* rather than *
       (case
        when this.testtype in (
                select testtype
                from   Offer o                  -- Remove AS
                where o.testcenter=t.testcenter
             )
        then 'yes'
        else 'no'
        end
       ) as offered
from   Test t;                                  -- Remove AS
```